# Mews Captcha validation doesn't work when the form is embedded in an iframe

Tags: laravel, iframe, captcha

I'm trying to add a captcha to a form, everything works perfectly.
The moment I add that form to an iFrame I start getting a validation error from the captcha.
I'm using `Laravel 7.3` and `mews/captcha  3.2`

the error I get:

> Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid. in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:452

HTML code:

```
<span id="captchaspan"> {!! captcha_img('flat') !!}</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="refresh"><i class="fa fa-refresh" ></i></button>
```

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn-success').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/refresh-captcha',
            datatype:'json',
            success: function(data){
                $(".captcha span").html(data.captcha);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in the controller:

```
try {
    request()->validate(['captcha' => 'required|captcha']);
}catch (\Exception $e){
    file_put_contents('log.log', ' captcha problem '.$e,8);
    return back()->with('error', 'Captcha Error');
}
```

refresh Captcha method

```
public function refreshCaptcha()
{
    return response()->json(['captcha'=> captcha_img('flat')]);
}
```

**Important**: the problem occurs only when the form is embedded in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can help, but I had a problem with this library, after hours of trying to figure out the problem and analyzing it, the problem with the library itself, not well tested, anyways my problem was in the config/mews php captcha file there was a property that was called math, I just disabled it, and the check works perfectly now, I hope this can help anyone in the future :)
and if the captcha rule doesn't work try this:

```
'captcha' => 'required|' , new captchaRule()
```

along with a custom rule called captchaRule() that simply passes this test:

```
return captcha_check($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

for validation you should use captcha_check() function in your controller. pass the submitted captcha string to this function and get a boolean response for validation. like this :

```
if ( captcha_check($request->captcha) == false ) {
   return back()->with('invalid-captcha','incorrect captcha!')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this one:

```
composer require hpd/captcha
```

https://github.com/hamid-hpd/captcha.git